# override class function and call it though it is handled as its base class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism, overriding, virtual

So, let's say i got a base class like this:

```
class Whatever
{
    virtual void Execute() = 0;
};
```

And i got a class which implements `Whatever`:

```
class WhateverImplementation : public Whatever
{
    virtual void Execute();
}
```

And some other class:

```
class Container
{
private:
    Whatever *m_whatever;
public:
    void setWhatever(Whatever *whatever)
    {
        m_whatever = whatever;
    }
}
```

And i call `setWhatever(new WhateverImplementation());`,
the thread throws segmentation fault when calling `m_whatever->Execute()`.

Comment: `class WhateverImplementation` should be `class WhateverImplementation : public Whatever`? Also make your interface functions `public`.

Comment: yes, excuse me i forgot to put that in my answer

Comment: Where are you calling `m_whatever->Execute()`? Clearly this code is showing only parts of what you are doing and the omissions (the missing base and the missing call) do affect what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`WhateverImplementation` needs to be a subclass of `Whatever` for this to work, but your code doesn't reflect that. I'm a bit surprised your compiler doesn't complain about that.

Try

```
 class WhateverImplementation : virtual Whatever
 { .... };
```

(or something else instead of `virtual`, e.g. `public`. Explaining what you'd need here might be a bit much here.)

Also, are you sure you work on a `Container` instance, i.e. something like

```
Container mycontainer(); 
mycontainer.setWhatever(new WhateverImplementation);
```

?

Also, your use of `new` without any `delete` makes me suspect you might be building a memory leak, so make sure you destroy `m_whatever` when you don't need it anymore.

Furthermore, you have a **declaration** in your question, but no **definition**, and that might be bad (however, your compiler should complain).

Comment: i worked on a little 2D engine and this Engine class stores a pointer to a class named EventHandler, which is a interface. And in the game project i have to set the EventHandler by my Implementation, but when i call Handle (the function i override), i get a segmentation fault. And: Where should i put the "delete m_whatever" and what does the ": virtual Whatever" exactly=

Comment: Really, that are very complex basic C++ questions and I can't explain these in this context.